# Using Timer within an Android Service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that is going to act as an internal clock as part of another app, and it contains a Timer which runs every one second to update the time.

Problem is, when I close and re-open the app, the Service binds itself and all the code runs again in the service and then there are two Timers per second, and so on.

I've tried following the Local Service example, but the same thing happens  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Is it something to do with the bind/unbind of the service?

I'd like for just one process to run, so I'm looking for a way really to see if the process is running already, and if not then start it.

LocalService
`public class LocalService extends Service {

```
// This is the object that receives interactions from clients.
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private  long dateOfLastSync;
private  long timeNow;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private static Timer timer = new Timer();
private Context ctx;


/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

    // The LocalBinder provides the getService() method for clients to retrieve the current instance of LocalService.
    LocalService getService() {
        Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "getService");
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return LocalService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "onCreate");
    ctx = this; 
    startService();        
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "onDestroy");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void startService()
{           
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 1000);
}

private class mainTask extends TimerTask
{ 
    public void run() 
    {
        toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}    

public void getTimeFromServer()  {
    FetchServerTime fetchTime = new FetchServerTime();
    fetchTime.execute();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "onBind");
    getTimeFromServer();


    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public long getTimeNow() {
    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "getTimeNow");
  return timeNow;
}

public void startTimeCounter() {
    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "startTimeCounter");

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "onStartCommand");

    return START_STICKY;
}

private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        timeNow += 1000;
        Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "time is " + timeNow);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}; 

 class FetchServerTime extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Long> {

    private String mUrl;
    private Date date;
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    public FetchServerTime() {
        mUrl = "XXX";
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        (get server time code)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "Server time on post execute: " + result);
        timeNow = result;
        dateOfLastSync = result;
    }




}
```

`

InternalClockActivity

```
 public class InternalClockActivity extends Activity implements CanUpdateTime {
private TextView timeLabel;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d("INTERNALCLOCK", "onCreate - main");

    timeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    doBindService();
}

private LocalService mBoundService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // established, giving us the service object we can use to
        // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
        // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
        // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.


        mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
        // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
        // see this happen.
        mBoundService = null;
    }
};

private boolean mIsBound;

void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
    // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
    // supporting component replacement by other applications).

    bindService(new Intent(InternalClockActivity.this, 
            LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        // Detach our existing connection.
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    doUnbindService();
}

public void updateTime(String time){

    timeLabel.setText(time);

}
}
```

Comment: You used a Timer, not ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: Ah apologies! I had used ScheduledExecutorService before but then changed it recently, didn't look properly at what I was pasting. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created some static variables to see if the timer was running, i.e.

```
private static boolean isDownloadTaskRunning = false;

private void startService()
{
    if (!isDownloadTaskRunning) {
        // Timers are not running already

        // start timer to download date at intervals
        timerToDownloadNewData.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DownloadDateTask(), 0, TIMES.FIFTEEN_MINS.getSeconds());

        // set running to true
        isDownloadTaskRunning = true;
    }
}
```